# how to disable material ui autocomplete options

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm new to reactjs and material UI.
I have struck in Materia UI autocomplete https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-47kfg (without popper or 1st one).

Here I want to disable some country value based on some condition.

like if country is albania i want to disable the albania. user should able to select the country and the popper should not close on the click event.
[image]

i have tried like this

```
 <Paper disabled={option.children=='Albania'?true:false} {...options.containerProps} square>
            {options.children}
          </Paper>
```

I have tried but nothing is working.
can anyone resolve this

Comment: I didnt get what you trying to do, what does it means disable? it wont appear on auto complete?

Comment: @Dennisvash It should appear but the user should not able to select the desired value.

Comment: so make the condition in the state